# React,js App - Getting data using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to build a fast React.js app, basically a game.
I need to display 'live' data, but loading them from server using Ajax doesnt feel like the right way to do it. Its React.js, but Ajax isnt the synonym for reacting. I have an idea to use socket.io for this and some kind of backend system for keeping and processing the data, not loading them from database every time.

Is this a good idea or a right way to do a fast React.js app, or am I totally wrong?

Comment: Socket.io is perfect for real-time communications. That's what it's built for.

Answer (score 0):

Loading data from a server will be faster indeed if loaded from live memory directly instead of traditional database lookup.

Socket.io can be useful if you want to push data from server to client, with server side initiation.

React.js does not make things fast by itself really. It can make development faster.

Comment: I did a game some time ago with socket instead ajax and it improved performance by 10x. Although I found some complications regarding React/Redux updates of state.

Comment: yeah again, it depends on the type of the game, doing data communication every 10 seconds is not the same than every 16ms so it depends

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at Angular-Firebase and 3-way data binding. This is specifically for building real-time applications.
https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-three-way-data-binding-firebase-angularjs/